# WP_Query meta_query REGEXP

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am pretty much below beginner level for REGEX/REGEXP and have hit a blocking point in a project I am working in, where I am trying to get the ids for posts that match the search criteria , but I want to restrict the search between 2 sub-strings. I am trying to figure out is how to write the REGEXP in the meta_query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'custom',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $page,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'key',           
           'value' => "title*".$search."*_title",
           'compare' => 'REGEXP',
        )
    ),      
);
```

And an example of the field in the DB :

```
a:302:{s:5:"title";s:10:"Test title";s:6:"_title";s:19:"
```

Unfortunately none of the combinations I tried based on documentation of SQL REGEXP won't return any values and I am trying to understand how I can pull this off and would appreciate any input.

Also would rather stick to WP_Query for now even though an SQL LIKE "%title%{$search}%_title%" works perfectly , so an alternative solution would be how to set the compare to  'LIKE' and parse it '%' since that is not possible out of the box as the % get escaped I believe.

Comment: Looks like `'value' => "title.*".$search.".*_title",` might work.

Comment: Yes , was first thing I tried yet it doesn't work. Or at least not for my use case.